# dynamic datetime SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have an existing table with a column called EntryDate specified as datetime and in this format:  2012-11-26 14:47:15

How do I construct a SQL SELECT statement that selects all records that were entered in the last 14 days based on the current system date?

Comment: What have you tried so far, did you have a look into the datetime arithmetic of `mysql`? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I was having trouble with the DATE_SUB portion, a solution below showed me the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here u can do like that

```
 select date_sub(now(),interval 14 day)as Datebefore14days;
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EntryDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is:

```
WHERE EntryDate >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY )
```